# Vertically arrange three areas of equal height and show sentences in the center of those areas

Tags: layout

## The context

I want to computationally generate 1920x1080 PNG images containing text with different styles. Because `LaTeX` has rich features for styling text and documents can be compiled using the command line (therefore, it is convenient to create scripts), I decided to use `LaTeX`.

I want to create three areas with the same height arranged vertically and show a sentence in the center of those areas. The following image was created using Inkscape and it shows the result that I'm looking for.

[image]

## What I've tried

The following minimal working example shows one of my attempts to accomplish the desired result.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0mm,text margin right=0mm}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    This is a sentence in the first area.
  \end{center}
  \par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
  \begin{center}
    This is a sentence in the second area.
  \end{center}
  \par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
  \begin{center}
    This is a sentence in the third area.
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem with this document is that the three areas are not of the same size and that the sentences are not centered.

## What I know

I know that it is possible to create 1920x1080 PNG images from PDF files using `convert`.

```sh
$ convert -quality 100 -density 300 -resize 1920x1080 document.pdf document.png
```

We can use `ffprobe` to confirm the desired dimensions.

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height -print_format default=nw=1 document.png
```

```
width=1920
height=1080
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use minipages of fixed height:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=16cm]{standalone}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\newlength{\myheight}
\setlength{\myheight}{\dimexpr3cm-2\fboxrule}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow}

\begin{document}

  \nointerlineskip
  \hskip-\fboxrule\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\myheight]{16cm}
    \centering
    This is a sentence in the first area.
  \end{minipage}}%
  
  \nointerlineskip
  \hskip-\fboxrule\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\myheight]{16cm}
    \centering
    This is a sentence in the first area.
  \end{minipage}}%
  
  \nointerlineskip
  \hskip-\fboxrule\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][\myheight]{16cm}
    \centering
    This is a sentence in the first area.
  \end{minipage}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use TikZ:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ($(current page.north west)!0.33!(current page.south west)$) -- ($(current page.north east)!0.33!(current page.south east)$);
\draw ($(current page.north west)!0.66!(current page.south west)$) -- ($(current page.north east)!0.66!(current page.south east)$);
\node[text width=\linewidth,align=center] at ($(current page.north)!0.1667!(current page.south)$) {sentence 1};
\node[text width=\linewidth,align=center] at ($(current page.north)!0.5!(current page.south)$) {sentence 2};
\node[text width=\linewidth,align=center] at ($(current page.north)!0.8333!(current page.south)$) {sentence 3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]